# How Does Prebuilt SEO Work?

Tags: seo

As a web developer, I know that when it comes to ranking in Google a big part of your SEO is the content on each page of your website. Obviously, when I’ve built websites for clients in the past I took care to make sure any content they provided was optimized. However, I’ve recently been asked by a friend to look into what prebuilt website solution (Wix, Squarespace, etc) night best for him. I noticed that all of theses platforms tout that every website has SEO already already. How does this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a prebuilt website solution advertises that your site will "have good SEO", they are not talking about on-page content, which while very important is of course up to the user.

They are talking about one or more of these things that happen behind the scenes:

- Title and description tags
- Sitemap
- Header tags
- Image alt text
- Canonical tags
- Opengraph tags

Basically what they are saying is that if you use their WYSIWYG tool correctly, they will generate markup like this for you, which will improve your site's crawlability for search engines and visibility on social media.

Comment: So basically it’s more about the semtanics and best practices as far as HTML goes than actual SEO tactics. Thanks!